# How to access "this" inside a closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm very new to JavaScript and jQuery and I'm having trouble with a bit of code.

HTML:

```
<div class="toggle" style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;">test</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        jQuery(".toggle").on("click", function() {
            console.log("let the toggling begin!");

            jQuery(this).slideToggle(600, function(){ // slide up
                setTimeout(function(){ // wait 4 sec, then slide back down
                    jQuery(this).slideToggle(600)
                }, 4000);
            });
        });
    }
);
```

So the idea is that you click on the div, it slides up, then 4 seconds later slides back down. It doesn't work.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/zEqN9/2/

However, if I change the `this` inside each of the closures to `".toggle"`, then it does work.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/YZxMb/

So clearly the issue is my use of `this`.

I tried passing `this` as a parameter into each of the two closure functions, but that gave the error `Unexpected token this`.

How can I access the `this` variable from the inner functions?

Comment: Using "this" in a callback is a question that was probably asked 10000 times.

Comment: @Virus721 - I did several searches and read many of the related questions before submitting my question, but perhaps I used the wrong terminology when searching..

Comment: This is a common gotcha as it's meaning is defined at execution time and can change depending on how a function has  been called. There is a detailed discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Comment: Note that `jQuery(this).slideToggle(600).delay(4000).slideToggle(600);` will achieve the effect you're after in a way that is a lot easier to write and read. (Not that it's a bad idea to learn how to deal with the `this` issue, since there are other cases where you definitely need to know about that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a reference to `this` in slideToggle function.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        jQuery(".toggle").on("click", function() {
            console.log("let the toggling begin!");

            jQuery(this).slideToggle(600, function(){ // slide up
                var self = this; // <-- notice this
                setTimeout(function(){ // wait 4 sec, then slide back down
                    jQuery(self).slideToggle(600)
                }, 4000);
            });
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to specify a `this` for a *function* you expect to call out of context.

```
var foo = {
    bar: function () {
        setTimeout(function () { // though in a setTimeout
            console.log(this);
        }.bind(this), 0); // binding to `this` here means
    }
};

foo.bar(); // invoking it still has `this` of `foo`
```

Comment: True, but not fully supported (e.g. IE8).

Comment: There is a shim in the linked article for those browsers

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that for a jQuery event, the context of the function is explicitly set so that `this` refers to the target element - this is done for you by jQuery. However, the anonymous function for `setTimeout` doesn't have that context set for you - it gets the default global context, so `this` refers to the window.

What you need to do is grab a reference to the click event's context, and then use the reference in the timeout:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".toggle").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.slideToggle(600, function () { // slide up
            setTimeout(function () { // wait 4 sec, then slide back down
                $this.slideToggle(600);
            }, 4000);
        });
    });
});
```

However, as pointed out in a comment, this could be written as:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".toggle").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).slideToggle(600).delay(4000).slideToggle(600);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourThing = jQuery(this);

yourThing.slideToggle(600, function(){ // slide up
     setTimeout(function(){ // wait 4 sec, then slide back down
          yourThing.slideToggle(600)
     }, 4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your code to understand why:

```
setTimeout(function(){ // wait 4 sec, then slide back down
      console.log(jQuery(this)); //this one
      jQuery(this).slideToggle(600)
      }, 4000);
```

Open your console. You will see that, in the `setTimeout` function, $(this) refers to the window object.

Answer (score 0):

You need a create a referente to this,so when runs the function associate to setTimeout you can pass this reference.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            jQuery(".toggle").on("click", function() {
                console.log("let the toggling begin!");
                var that = this; // <--- reference to this
                jQuery(this).slideToggle(600, function(){ // slide up
                    setTimeout(function(){ // wait 4 sec, then slide back down
                        jQuery(that).slideToggle(600)
                    }, 4000);
                });
            });
        }
    );
```